# Set up .pac script with python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, proxy

I work in a company protected by a proxy and it seems that python does not use the address provided by the .pac script. In fact, I can access the APIs and download files if I use google chrome, but everything is blocked when I try to do the same with my python code.

The .pac script is given here on windows (10), I can't modify any parameters due to company security strategy:
[image: This is where pac script is used, I can't change it due to company security strategy.]

I tried to contact IT, they gave me the adress behind the proxy so I tried to change http_proxy and https_proxy environnement variable and I also tried to put theses parameters directly into my python code like this:

```
import requests

url = "https://api.dictionaryapi.dev/api/v2/entries/en/hello"

proxies = {
       "https": "http://user:password@proxyadress:port/",
       "http": "http://user:password@proxyadress:port/"
}

r = requests.get(url, proxies=proxies, verify=False)
```

With this, I got a error 407:
`ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required')))`

How can I use this .pac script with my python code ? It seems that The proxy doesn't detect my credentials...

NB: I tried Pypac package, doesn't work either